# Table Sorter sorting and filtering didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have dynamically table and I use table sorter pager is working well, but when I try to filter some columns it just returns me to page 0 and nothing happened. Somewhere I try to sort them by clicking on th and other strange thing is when I type in the input box debug mode on table sorter say is ok.

```
       var $table = $(".track-grid table.tablesorter");
        var pagesize = $('.pagesize').val();
        $table.tablesorter({
            widthFixed: true,
            cssChildRow: 'infoRow',
            widgets: ['filter'],
            debug: true,
            widgetOptions: {

                filter_hideFilters: true,
                // filter_anyMatch replaced! Instead use the filter_external option
                // Set to use a jQuery selector (or jQuery object) pointing to the
                // external filter (column specific or any match)
                filter_external: '.search',
                // add a default type search to the first name column
                //filter_defaultFilter: { 1: '~{query}' },
                // include column filters
                filter_ignoreCase:false

            }

        });

        $table.on('filterInit', function () {
            $table.tablesorterPager({
                container: $(".pager"),
                ajaxUrl: `track/getEvents?page={page}&size={size}&totalCount=` + totalCount,

                customAjaxUrl: function (table, url) {
                    return url;
                },
                ajaxProcessing: function (data) {

                    $('.tablesorter tbody').html(data.result.eventsHtml);

                    $('#trackOverlay').hide();
                    return [parseInt(data.result.totalEventsCount)];
                },
                page: 0,
                processAjaxOnInit: true,
                output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})',
                updateArrows: true,
                fixedHeight: false,
                removeRows: false,
                savePages: false,
                cssNext: '.next',  // next page arrow
                cssPrev: '.prev',  // previous page arrow
                cssFirst: '.first', // go to first page arrow
                cssLast: '.last',  // go to last page arrow
                cssGoto: '.gotoPage', // page select dropdown - select dropdown that set the "page" option

                cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
                cssPageSize: '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option
                cssDisabled: 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
                cssErrorRow: 'tablesorter-errorRow' // error information row

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ajaxUrl` option needs to include a filter value. If you look at the example in the [documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxurl), you'll see this:

```
ajaxUrl: "http://mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol}",
```

The `{filterList:fcol}` adds the filter to the server request.

If the built-in implementation doesn't work for you, use the [`customAjaxUrl` callback](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-customajaxurl) to modify the ajax url.

Comment: Thanks i found it yesterday and works fine but now i have problem with sorting column  i know how to sort it but i dont know wich column is clicked. When i clicked in every column on my table it react the same i try to get  <th> html to make diff logic for diff columns but customAjaxUrl:  returning the url before i get the name of column can you give me some advice ?

Comment: There is also a `{sortList:col}` within the `ajaxUrl` that passes a list of columns and sort direction to the server.